# Best comprehensive guide to number terminology

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

I just encountered the [prime number wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_prime_numbers) and when looking through some of them, or even [regular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/600_(number)), you see dozens of new terms you never encounter in other areas of math such as:

- centered pentagonal number
- nontotient
- Harshad number
- sphenic number
- balanced prime
- sexy prime
- happy number
- ... phew

I have looked through a bit of the different areas of math but I haven't ever seen stuff like this with all these names for different numbers and the features of individual numbers. I assume this all is covered in Number Theory, but I'm just not sure what the best place is to look it up quickly and thoroughly.

I would like to know if there is a book or anything (preferably something freely available online) other than Wikipedia that goes through *all* of the different possible number theory terms (or as many as possible to be thorough), and perhaps any theorems/lemmas/proofs if that's the style. I like the books that are concise and just pure Lemma/Theorem/Definition -> Lemma/Theorem/Definition -> Lemma/Theorem/Definition ... no fluff, if at all possible.

Comment: These are pretty arcane terms, rarely used in mainstream number theory. I think wikipedia or looking them up on line one at a time is your best bet.

Comment: Agreeing with Ethan, as he knows what goes into a Number Theory book (https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/682005.Elementary_Number_Theory). Another source is the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, oeis.org. E.g., if you type in "sphenic", out comes http://oeis.org/A007304 and several other related pages which will probably tell you everything you could want to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/)

[Prime pages](https://primes.utm.edu/)

[OEIS](https://oeis.org/)

[Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/user/numberphile)

[standupmaths](https://www.youtube.com/user/standupmaths)

[singingbanana](https://www.youtube.com/user/singingbanana)

[Mathologer](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1_uAIS3r8Vu6JjXWvastJg)

Come to mind. Numberphile has videos on sets, sexy primes, and happy numbers. If you don't have some elementary set theory knowledge, number theory will be basically impossible.

**EDIT** Also forgot [List of Mathematical symbols](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols),[List of math jargon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_jargon),[Glossary of math](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_mathematics) etc.

Comment: If you want basic set theory, RDS numbertheory h9mework thread on mersenneforum. I failed the preliminaries.